# Vue.js - How to determine if an axios request has no response data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to test if the IP address provided by a user is the expected IP, so i send a request to that IP address which is expected to be running the API service, if the IP is correct it return success but if the IP is wrong it returns no response data, in the front-end of the application which is Vue.js i want to be able to know what happened and fire an alert to the user, if its successful i'm able to do that but if its not nothing happens, how do i get that error message?

this is my code

```
PublisherUrl().get('/api/publish-lv/').then(()=>{
           
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Publisher Connected Successfully'
            })
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
          
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Publisher Device Unreachable'
            })
           
        })
    }
```

Comment: you can receive the response inside `then`. Based on the response you can decide what to do

Answer (score 4):

the callback function inside `then` has a parameter response that returns the data, headers and status ...

```
PublisherUrl().get('/api/publish-lv/').then((response)=>{
  if(response.data.length===0){
     Toast.fire({
                icon: 'info',
                title: 'No data'
            })
  }else{
     Toast.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Publisher Connected Successfully'
            })
  }

   }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error)
          
            Toast.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Publisher Device Unreachable'
            })
           
        })
    }
```

Comment: for what am trying to do, if the response.data is zero, it means the IP address provided is correct, just that there is no data available, and that will even return an empty array, this time there is no response data, this is because the user provided an IP address of a computer that is not hosting the back-end application, and i need to catch this error and prompt the user to provide the right IP address.